# My custom 404 error won't work in certain circumstances

Tags: video, background, http-status-code-404

When I purposefully bring up my error page to test my custom 404 page, it appears if I mistype it as "www.site.com/ind" (should be index.html but I cut it off). Now After the second forward slash, when I bring a 404 from trying to access a nonexistent file, my 404 doesn't show my video or sound playing in the background for my 404. I've attached a link below so you can see what I mean. The left is the error that isn't showing my video, the right is what I want (before you all comment on it, yes those are the Asari from Mass Effect 2).

javascript for the video:

```
var vid = document.getElementById("bgvid");
var pauseButton = document.querySelector("");

function vidFade() {
vid.classList.add("stopfade");
}

vid.addEventListener('ended', function()
{
// only functional if "loop" is removed   
vid.pause();
// to capture IE10
vidFade();
});
```

Here's the video/audio code for the 404:

```
<video autoplay id="bgvid" loop>
<source src="404.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
</video>
<div class="br" />
<div id="video_box">
<center><div id="video_overlays"><p class="quote"><br>ERROR 404!<br>You know the drill. Either I fucked up or you did.<br></p></div></center>
</div>
<audio src="404.mp3" autoplay loop>
<p>If you are reading this, it is because your browser does not support the audio element.</p>
<embed src="404.mp3" width="180" height="90" hidden="true" />
</audio>
```

Reference image: http://oi62.tinypic.com/wjc103.jpg

Comment: Sorry my description was vague, by second forward slash I mean if I type "site/index/music.html" where that page doesn't exist instead of "site/ind", which has one forward slash.

Comment: -bump- nobody knows?